# What should be the ViewModel members visibility?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've came across an interesting issue for which I've found no explanation yet...

Given the very simple MVVM WPF application below, why is the list bound to the combo box only if its visibility in the ViewModel is set to `public` ?

Changing the `TestList` visibility to `internal` raises no error or warning at compile time but leaves the combo box empty at run time.

Quoting [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `internal` types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly.

And this issue is happening despite the fact that the View and the ViewModel are defined in the same assembly.

Here is how the code looks like:

**Model:**

```
class TestModel
{
    internal List<string> Musketeers { get; private set; }

    public TestModel()
    {
        Musketeers = new List<string> { "Athos", "Porthos", "Aramis" };
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Width="250" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding TestList}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    TestModel myModel = new TestModel();

    public List<string> TestList
    {
        get
        {
            return myModel.Musketeers;
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged members are below ...
}
```

Comment: _Aren't the View and ViewModel in the same assembly?_  I don't we can answer that.  Where you have have them defined?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Oops, you're right! I've fixed my wording now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ViewModel` with `internal` access is visible for `View`, but is not visible to [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) class, which really makes the binding work.

`{Binding TestList}` is transformed into `Binding` class instance, which has no knowledge about `internal` members of your `ViewModel` class.

Comment: Not that I'd recommend doing this, but now I'm wondering if you could get away with using `internal` if your assembly also had an `InternalsVisibleTo` of the `PresentationCore` assembly...

Comment: Maybe it could be done this way, but what's the point of doing such a thing?

Comment: Absolutely no reason whatsoever :) - I just like knowing what is *possible* in any situation.

Answer (score 6):

This is because Data Binding uses reflection and that in turn adhers to the visibility of items. Since data binding is implemented outside of your assembly - inside the WPF libraries - it cannot see non-public members.

Binding to a non-existing member will not issue a runtime error but rather a debug output with a message containing details about the missing member.